# Renaming Custom Preferences in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've got some parameters creating custom preferences in NetSuite.

By default they are grouped in a **General** heading under custom preferences. However I see other bundles have their custom preferences grouped:

[image]

How do I group my preferences in my own "named" section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do that. NetSuite automatically does the grouping for the preferences when you install the bundle.

What you can go is create a bundle of your preferences and install it in your account.  I have not tried this so I don't know if it will work.

Comment: @Rusty is correct. You are seeing different name because it is based on the bundle name it was included. You may put yours in a bundle too and provide your preferred name and then install.