# Trigger script on change of a custom preference

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Further to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351542/renaming-custom-preferences-in-netsuite) around custom (general) preferences, is there a way to trigger a script whenever a general preference is changed in the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page is not scriptable so I don't think it is possible.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to put it out there before I put a scheduled "check/update" in place around custom preferences for my bundle.